# getHeight() vs getLayoutParams().height

Tags: android, view, height

What is the difference between `getHeight()` and `getLayoutParams().height` of a `View`? I have a `View` (GoogleAdView) and I want to hide it, I set `getLayoutParams().height` to zero but the ad's height (`ad.getHeight()`) is not zero.

Is there a way to hide the `View` so that it doesn't occupy space in the layout?

I've tried to set its visibility to `GONE` or to set `ad.getLayoutParams().height` to zero but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`LayoutParams.height` is the height you *wish* your view will have once laid out and could be set to particular constants like WRAP_CONTENT, `getHeight()` returns the actual height (it returns 0 until the view isn't laid out). See [How Android Draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) and [View - Size, padding and margins](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SizePaddingMargins).

As Michael said, you have to call requestLayout().

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to hide a view and ignore it in layouts is to use

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If this is not working for you, you need to find out why. Trying to tweak the sizes is not a good path.

If you have problems with your layout, post it here.

Comment: my problem is that if I do with setVisibility(View.GONE), the space were was ad remains unoccupied and the layout doesn't resize itself. I've tried with ad.refreshDrawableState(); but still the layout doesn't resize...

Comment: refreshDrawableState() will not help. Did you call refreshLayout() after hiding the view?

Comment: my layout object (LinearLayout) doesn't have this method (refreshLayout()).

Comment: Give android:weight="1" for the layout which is not getting resized and try with setVisibility(View.GONE); for ad view.